# extracting few values from exception detail message in java

Tags: java, selenium, nosuchelementexception

How can we extract few details of an exception in java.

With `getMessage()` method I'm able to fetch the detailed Message of an exception ,I just want a few detail like Session info:, Session Id:, of that exception.

**Note:**

To be specific I'm using `selenium.NoSuchElementException`

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a regular expression with capture groups... This might fail when a later version of Selenium changes its exception message format, but it's the only way you can extract from the Exception.

Another alternative would be to get the Session ID from another source... Like the driver... [RemoteWebDriver.getSessionId()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getSessionId%28%29)

Regex example using an exception from [another question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28433002/org-openqa-selenium-nosuchelementexception-no-such-element-received-when-i-cl)

```
try {
    throw new NoSuchElementException(
            "no such element (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.111) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 30.05 seconds For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00' System info: host: 'AS-Ramesh', ip: '*******', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_17' Session ID: 0e85209c610382395e8dee65a9766bd2 Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\\Users\\rameshp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir27484_24934}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=40.0.2214.111, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]");
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    Pattern sessionId = Pattern.compile(".*\\(Session info: (.*?)\\).*Session ID: (\\w+).*");
    Matcher m = sessionId.matcher(e.getMessage());
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // chrome=40.0.2214.111
        System.out.println(m.group(2)); // 0e85209c610382395e8dee65a9766bd2
    }
}
```

Comment: The argument inside the `NoSuchElementException()` is Dynamic as the Exception message will change as the driver gets the new instance of WebDriver like firefox or i.e . Here I'm overriding the `onException()` method of` AbstractWebDriverEventListener` class. And printing the detail of exception by just calling throwable. So inside try block I have put throw new `NoSuchElementException(throwable.getMessage)`. But it is not working. Kindly suggest the other way if possible. Or where I'm making mistake? @Adam